# Expanding a shell variable in a script

Tags: bash, shell, variables, syntax

If I define my archive folder it in my environment and export it, how do I access it in a shell script and run a program?

```
ARCHIVE=/home/kschmidt/public_html/CS265/Assignments/DrMath/Archive
export ARCHIVE
./prob1
```

Currently, my prob1 contains this code which I get an error when I try to run.

```
#!/bin/bash
print ARCHIVE
```

Answer (score 1):

You expand a shell variable by prefixing it with a `$`, and print it with `echo` or `printf` command - shell doesn't have a `print` command:

```
echo "$ARCHIVE"
```

or

```
printf '%s\n' "$ARCHIVE"
```

As an aside, it is not good to use relative paths (as in `./prob1`) in a script, unless you are explicitly `cd`ing to the directory where `prob1` exists.  So, either:

- do an explicit `cd` to the script directory before invoking it with a relative path

or

- use an absolute path (as in /path/to/prob1)

---

Related:

- [Why is printf better than echo - on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/201820)
- [Shell Parameter Expansion - GNU Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)
- [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10067266/6862601)

Answer (score 0):

prob1's code should be like:

```
#!/bin/bash
bash $ARCHIVE
```

then prob1 run like this:

```
bash prob1
```

I hope this help.

Comment: That is perfect thanks! One more quick question. How would I be able to loop through all the files in the directory and print them?

Comment: That's simple one, here is snippet  https://gist.github.com/iamshanto/84a42709c7ef024f9150ccd698365d11